# Execute Stored Procedure in the same LightSwitch connection

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an HTML client and after inserting an entity, I need to execute a stored procedure.

This stored procedure needs to update the status of the inserted entity, so I need it to run in the same connection to not be locked.

How do I get the connection used internally by the LightSwitch application?

Thanks a Lot, Ariel

Comment: Can you give us more information about the use case?  Are you looking to modify the entity before it gets posted to the data source?  Or are you looking to post it to the data source, then run the stored proc?  Can you give us a quick breakdown of what's driving this from a solution design context?

Comment: Sounds like you could maybe write this as a **trigger** that would be automatically fired when a new entity is inserted ....